# Frequency of distinct values SQL

Tags: count, google-bigquery, distinct, frequency

Is there a way to (1) transform values in one column (in seconds) to minutes and then (2) get the frequency/occurrence of the distinct values (minutes)?

I used this for step 1:

```
SELECT
  ROUND(tripduration/60) AS duration
FROM
  TABLE
```

This gives me the duration in minutes, as something like this:

| duration |
| --- |
| 11 |
| 16 |
| 11 |
| ... |
| 11 |

But for step 2, how do I get the sum of how often the values occurred, to something like this in a descending order:

| duration | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 11 | 4000 |
| 13 | 3900 |
| 16 | 2500 |
| ... | ... |
| 14 | 230 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation, if I understand correctly:

```
SELECT ROUND(tripduration/60) AS duration, COUNT(*) as frequency
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ROUND(tripduration/60)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I get the error "SELECT list expression references column tripduration which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:14]". I wonder if that has to do with the division? tripduration is an integer that I simply divide by 60 to get it in minutes.

Comment: @mabiel . . . This should be fine in almost any database, but you can try `GROUP BY duration`.  You still have not provided a database tag on the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error for tripduration column, try this:

`SELECT  duration, frequency FROM  (SELECT duration , COUNT(*) as frequency FROM (SELECT ROUND(tripduration/60,2) AS duration FROM TABLE) d GROUP BY duration) t ORDER BY frequency DESC;`